# About create a orthonormal base with orthogonal image in a finite dimensional subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I'm studying an article about contractive operators (operators $A$ such that $||A|| \leq 1$) and I'm having a hard time with a construction of a orthonormal base with a orthogonal image: [image]
Where $V$ is a finite dimensional subspace of a separable hilbert $H$, $A:V \rightarrow H$ is a contractive operator and $W = A(V)$. Also, $S_V = \left\lbrace v \in V:||v|| = 1 \right\rbrace$.

I tried to construct the base using the fact of $S_V\cap\operatorname{span}\left\lbrace v_i:i\leq j\right\rbrace^\perp$ be closed and bounded in finite dimensional space, consequentially compact, we can use that $||A\cdot||$ is continuous to find a orthonormal base satisfying (i) and (ii). But this doesn't guarantee to me the orthogonality of $\left\lbrace Av_i:i<n\right\rbrace$.

The only important thing of this construction to the rest of the proof is that the orthonormal base with orthogonal image by $A$ and the fact of $||Av_i|| > 0$ if and only if $i <m$. Any tips and constructions that make a base satisfying this will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking. First of all, I don't understand what you mean when you say that you "tried to construct the base manually". Do you mean that you looked at an example of a contractive operator $A$?

Comment: @BenGrossmann I'm asking an explicit construction of a base satisfying (i) and (ii). When I say ""tried to construct the base manually" I'm saying that I tried to construct without Gram-Schmidt. I'll edit the question to be more clear.

Comment: Regarding the guarantee of orthogonality: I suspect that condition (ii) is actually written a bit inaccurately. What I think that they meant to say is that for every $j$, $v_{j+1}$ is selected from $\text{span}\{v_i:i \leq j\}^\perp$ such that 
$$
\|Av_{j+1}\| = \max\{\|Av\|: v \in S_V \cap \text{span}\{v_i:i \leq j\}^\perp\}
$$

Comment: But how could the construction be "explicit" without an example of an operator $A$? Are you looking for an algorithm to construct such a basis?

Comment: @BenGrossmann Yes, exactly. The only condition to the operator is $||A|| \leq 1$ and I want an algorithm to construct a basis satisfying these conditions.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Yes, the condition (ii) is exactly what you said

Comment: If the condition is as I said, then it's clear that $v_j$ is orthogonal to $v_1,\dots,v_{j-1}$ because $v_j$ is selected from a set of vectors satisfying this condition. So, you can conclude that it's an orthogonal and (since the vectors are taken from $S_V$) hence orthonormal basis

Comment: It seems as though this basis is the set of "right singular vectors" from the [singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) of $A|_V:V \to W$

Comment: I'll look to this singular value decomposition, thanks! And yeah, we guarantee the orthonormality of the basis, the problem is guarantee the orthogonality of the image.

Comment: @BenGrossmann SVD solved my problem, thanks!!!